# Error while spawning my robot in gazebo using gazebo_ros

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following launch file:

```
<launch>
  <!-- roslaunch arguments -->
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
 
  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of 
    the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="worlds/empty.world" />
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)" />
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
    <arg name="headless" value="false" />
  </include>
 
  <!-- urdf xml robot description loaded on the Parameter Server-->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find labrob_description)/urdf/labrob.urdf'" />
 
  <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
  <node name="labrob_spawn" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" output="screen" 
    args="-urdf -param robot_description -model labrob" />
</launch>
```

I get the following errors, which I cannot understand:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gazebo_ros/gzserver]: can't locate node [gzserver] in package [gazebo_ros]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gazebo_ros/gzclient]: can't locate node [gzclient] in package [gazebo_ros]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gazebo_ros/spawn_model]: can't locate node [spawn_model] in package [gazebo_ros]
```

My issue is that I could easily run this launch file one month ago when I stopped using ros for a bit and now that I tried again I can't.

Has anything changed about gazebo_ros package? Why do I get this error and what should I change to fix this error?

Thanks for answering,

Chris

*1st EDIT:*

I tried also something simple as:

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

but I got the following errors:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gazebo_ros/gzserver]: can't locate node [gzserver] in package [gazebo_ros]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gazebo_ros/gzclient]: can't locate node [gzclient] in package [gazebo_ros]
```

I am kind of lost on what is going wrong on a simple command like this.

The `gazebo` command works fine. I also checked the directory /opt/ros/kinetic/share/gazebo_ros and I didn't find any worlds file. Should I remove the gazebo_ros package and install it again ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245030/error-while-spawning-my-robot-in-gazebo-using-gazebo_ros/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the issue by backing up my src file of my workspace and reinstalling it in a new workspace.

The issue probably arised because at past I used a source launch file from the gazebo_ros package probably causing an error at the different existing names.

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, it turns out I was having the same problem with the gazebo_ros package with gazebo7 and indigo on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I solved in a similar way: by first issuing "catkin_make clean" on the catkin environment and also deleting manually a folder called "gazebo_ros" in the "catking/devel/shared" path. This last step was an attempt to erase all traces of a manual installation of gazebo_ros I tried to do. It turns out that was the cause of the problem. Now, it is solved!

---

Originally posted by [ewerlopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/25852/ewerlopes/) with karma: 21 on 2016-12-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VincyXiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/42174/vincyxiao/) on 2019-06-07**:
Thanks a lot! It works for me.
Delete manually a folder called "gazebo_ros" in the "catking/devel/shared" path and then catkin_make

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved this problem.!
Frist : you should check your gazebo_ros is installed or not. just  'roscd gazebo_ros'  or 'rospack list'.if not,you can install it by type 'sudo apt-get install ros--gazebo-ros' ;
you can also sudo apt-get install ros--gazebo-*
Then: source /opt/ros//setup.bash
fanal : you can use roscore && rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo
or roslaunch gazebo_ros emply_world.launch

---

Originally posted by [emigmo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28503/emigmo/) with karma: 11 on 2016-12-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dhruv7396](https://answers.ros.org/users/33590/dhruv7396/) on 2018-02-06**:
Worked perfectly, it seems roslaunch was unable to source my gazebo package.